# Add records to an array element at a specific index using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to add values to a specific key inside a specific array element using jq. I have the following JSON:

```
[
   {
      "name":"element1",
      "properties":{
         "hardwareProfile":{
            "vmSize":"vm_size"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "name":"element2",
      "properties":{
         "hardwareProfile":{
            "vmSize":"vm_size"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

And I'd like to add information to the `properties.hardwareProfile` key inside the first element so it becomes:

```
[
   {
      "name":"element1",
      "properties":{
         "hardwareProfile":{
            "vmSize":"vm_size",
            "newProperty":"new_value",
            "anotherNewProperty":"another_new_value"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "name":"element2",
      "properties":{
         "hardwareProfile":{
            "vmSize":"vm_size"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I've had limited success adding the information doing this:

```
$ VM_SIZE_INFO="{newProperty:\"new_value\", anotherNewProperty:\"another_new_value\"}"

$ jq "[.[0].properties.hardwareProfile + $VM_SIZE_INFO]" resources.json
[
  {
    "vmSize": "Standard_B8ms",
    "newProperty": "new_value",
    "anotherNewProperty": "another_new_value"
  }
]
```

But this doesn't really work for me since I need the full json on the output.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: I've added what got me the closest to the result I need so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea was right, but by virtue of using `+` on the object at first index, you lost the objects at other indices. You need to use the append operator `+=`

If its the "first" object to be added, use the object designator `.[0]` to add the records of your choice.

Also using a shell variable with double quotes is not a right way to import JSON shell content to your `jq` program. Use the `--argjson` option to import directly

```
jq --argjson new '{ "newProperty":"new_value", "anotherNewProperty":"another_new_value" }' \
    '.[0].properties.hardwareProfile += $new' json
```

or with a variable wrapping the JSON content under single quotes

```
VM_SIZE_INFO='{ "newProperty":"new_value", "anotherNewProperty":"another_new_value" }'
```

and doing

```
jq --argjson new "$VM_SIZE_INFO" '.[0].properties.hardwareProfile += $new' json
```